# Hide the acrobat reader tool bar and capturing the print event from my application

Tags: asp.net

I want to capture the print event from my asp.net web application and also i want to disable the save button from acrobat tool bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Internet Explorer you can catch onBeforePrint event via JavaScript, but other browser do not support it. Read [more about it in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534977/javascript-event-handler-for-print). About save button in Acrobat tool bar - I think it is not possible to disable it from JavaScript or ASP.NET, but I maybe wrong here.