# Capturing Print Events via Jquery/JS/Browser Specific APIs

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mozilla, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to ask if there is a way to capture the print events (like IE onbeforeprint and onafterprint events). Actually I would like to do more. I want to know if I could interrupt printing, cancel it or may be change the print option all together to have a myPrint option. 
       Can this be achieved through plug-ins/extensions/XPCOM ? 
Actually I want a cross-browser control and I dont mind having separate control in different browsers.. Like via a plug-in in IE, extension/XPCOM in mozilla and Chrome extensions if possible..

Answer (score 1):

I'll quote [danieltalsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22452/danieltalsky) answer to the [Javascript Event Handler for Print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534977/javascript-event-handler-for-print) post since I think that the same applies in your situation:

> In IE there are the nonstandard window.onBeforePrint() and window.onAfterPrint() event listeners. There isn't a non-IE way to do it that I know of, however.
>
> What kinds of changes are you trying to make? It's possible that your problem could be solved by specifying different rules for your print stylesheet.

Comment: Hi Arnaud. As said in the question, I want to do a whole lot of things, not just change the styles using print CSS. Also I am open to having COM components or plug-in.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3619706/198953 for a good solution cross browsers.