# Check for when a user has selected to print using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, printing

When a user chooses "File > Print" on a browser such as Firefox or Internet Explorer, or clicks on a link that runs the below javascript

```
window.print();
```

Is there a way to conditionally check for this mode and disable SOME javascript.

I am trying to do this because I have a plugin that adds in its own custom markup for rounded borders and even in a print specific stylesheet I can not override the styling for these, I dont want the borders to appear when printing out the page.

**EDIT:** Unrelated to the plugin there are style changes done via javascript that is used to create a tabbed user interface and I have done print specific CSS to override the styling and it works fine when I use the Firefox web developer toolbar > CSS > Display CSS by Media type > Print.. but when I print it out it doesn't work, the javascript takes over and changes the styling.. if I disable javascript completely then the printing obviously works fine again.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just display:none in the print specific stylesheet ?

Comment: I have tried already, the nodes are not standard and the display:none !important; css changed nothing.

Comment: @Pricey: you probably don't have this problem any more, but I thought I would let you know that modern browsers have a better solution.  See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
window.old_print=window.print
window.print=function() {
    alert('doing things');
    window.old_print();
}
```

but this will only catch calls to `print()` from inside the page javascript.

Did you try putting `!important` on print-specific stylesheet?

Comment: Both answers make it pretty clear that I can't cover every case so I am in a bit of a pickle. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 19):

There's a universal solution for this, along with a bit of hackery for older browsers.  You *can* override the `print()` method in all browsers:

```
(function (oldPrint) { 
    window.print = function () {
        document.getElementById("hideThis").style.display = 'none';
        oldPrint();
    }
})(window.print);
```

The problem here is that it will not fire for users pressing Ctrl+P or accessing the file menu to print.  Internet Explorer has a solution by way of the [`onbeforeprint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536906(VS.85).aspx) event:

```
if ("onbeforeprint" in window) {
    var hideEl = document.getElementById("hideThis");
    window.onbeforeprint = function () { 
        hideEl.style.display = 'none';
    }
    window.onafterprint = function () {
        hideEl.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

As for other browsers, you can add an event listener to a print MediaQueryList as [detailed by TJ VanToll in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11060206/94197):

```
if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mqList = window.matchMedia("print"),
        hideEl = document.getElementById("hideThis");

    mqList.addListener(function (mql) {
        hideEl.style.display = mql.matches ? 'none' : '';
    }); 
}
```

And putting it all together:

```
(function () {
    var hideEl = document.getElementById("hideThis");

    // HTML5 spec, IE 5.5+, Firefox 6.0+
    if ("onbeforeprint" in window) {
        window.onbeforeprint = function () { 
            hideEl.style.display = 'none';
        }
        window.onafterprint = function () {
            hideEl.style.display = '';
        }
    }

    // Chrome 9+, Opera 12.1+, Safari 5.1+
    else if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mqList = window.matchMedia("print");

        mqList.addListener(function (mql) {
            hideEl.style.display = mql.matches ? 'none' : '';
        }); 
    }

    // Your fallback method, only working for JS initiated printing
    else {    
        (function (oldPrint) { 
            window.print = function () {
                hideEl.style.display = 'none';
                oldPrint();
            }
        })(window.print);
    }
})();
```

Comment: See a workaround for other browsers [at this newer SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11060206/71650)

Comment: @Nathan: thanks, I've updated the answer and credited your source.

Comment: Cool, I'm impressed as always.

Comment: The "all together" solution doesn't work in latest Firefox (v32) because although it supports window.matchMedia, printing causes a clone of the document to be created, so the event handler is never called. See [this Mozilla bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774398). I worked around this by testing for onbeforeprint and onafterprint support, then using this in preference to window.matchMedia