# formating bxslider html and style for printing

Tags: jquery, css, printing, bxslider

Is there a way to disable bxslider jquery plugin and display all content linear when a user clicks print?

http://bxslider.com/

Nevermind. I am going to delete the jquery plugin and go for something more functional.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this css:

```
@media print {
    .bxslider * {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

But it is a bit of a hack and might not look amazing, but you can mess with your print css styles in this way. You could also try `display: list-item !important;` if `block` doesn't look nice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay Watson. Unfortunately neither of those worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3619689/1055987 you could try removing the `bxslider` class while printing :

```
window.old_print=window.print
window.print=function() {
    jQuery(".bxslider").removeClass("bxslider");
    window.old_print();
}
```

but personally I would rather prefer to use a CSS solution when possible as suggested by @Watson

**NOTE** : I used jQuery to remove the class since you must be using it already with bxslider ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solution and I found this one:
https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/112
which is the only one working for me.