# Add eventListener to window.print()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I have page which contains `textArea`'s. If some of this textArea's contains too many text, user can't see all text (only if use scroll).

So i add js-function to make textArea height fit text inside :

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
        $('textarea').each(function() {
            resizeTextArea(this);
        });
    });
```

But when i use `window.print();` this behaviour doesn't apllied to textArea's. 
So i have idea to add some eventListener to `print` event, but my researching show that there are only some listeners for some browsers like IE or FireFox.

So is there any other solution that could help me print textArea's with fully visible text inside?

How textArea looks in print-window :

[image: print-image]

How textArea looks on page which is used for print :

[image]

Comment: When you're calling `window.print();` yourself - why don't you also call `resizeTextArea()` beforehand?

Comment: @maja, do you mean on document.ready? I try to do it, but i understand that print window takes height of textArea that are at the page (if i make screen size less on page from where print is applied, then height of textArea would be perfect)

Comment: Perhaps you have a link demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435906/print-when-textarea-has-overflow

Comment: @levi, with this can be problems...

Comment: @StephenThomas, thanks, i will try to implement it. Just one problem - all textarea's are generated from server side, it can make some troubles

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24996182/3917754 this answer seems to work... but need to check in all Browsers