# Javascript Printing Event

Tags: javascript, printing, html5-canvas

I am drawing a chart in an HTML5 canvas.  When the chart is printed I would like to use "printer friendly" colors.  Is there any event that gets triggered, or anything I can add to the media="print" css that will indicate that the page is being printed so that I can re-render the canvas with the correct colors?

I wanted to avoid using a "printer friendly version" button.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534977/javascript-event-handler-for-print

Comment: Unfortunately onbeforeprint doesn't work in Chrome, so that won't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's the point I'm trying to make. There is no javascript printing event otherwise Google would be using it to print its gmaps.